# Error in AWS PowerShell tool: The specified key does not exist

Tags: powershell, amazon-s3

When I try to copy a file between buckets I get the error "The specified key does not exist." Apparently the error is visual because the file is copied correctly. I'm running PowerShell on an AWS VM.

Command

```
Copy-S3Object -BucketName cfd-recordings-3 -Key test.txt -DestinationBucket cfd-recordings-3/test1 -DestinationKey test.txt
```

Error

```
> Copy-S3Object : The specified key does not exist. At line:1 char:1
> 
> + Copy-S3Object -BucketName cfd-recordings-3 -Key test.txt -Destination ...
> + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Amazon.PowerShe...yS3ObjectCmdlet:CopyS3ObjectCmdlet)
> [Copy-S3Object], InvalidOperationException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Exception,Amazon.PowerShell.Cmdlets.S3.CopyS3ObjectCmdlet
```

I have tried to change the bucket and the file to copy and I always get the same visual error.

I also tried downloading to the PC with the same command and in this case the error was not displayed.

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop> Copy-S3Object -BucketName cfd-recordings-3 -Key test.txt -LocalFile .\Desktop\test.txt
```

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4800344)

Comment: The key has 0 length, so it's empty.

Comment: `cfd-recordings-3/test1` is not a valid bucket name, this command cannot work.

Answer (score 0):

After doing multiple tests with different types of buckets I discovered that the error is in the wrong location of the folder path together with the -DestinationBucket. Moving the folder path to the -DestinationKey fixed the problem.

Bad code:

```
-DestinationBucket cfd-recordings-3/test1 -DestinationKey test.txt
```

Good code:

```
-DestinationBucket cfd-recordings-3 -DestinationKey test1/test.txt
```